# what does virtualenv faster than venv mean? just when creation? or when running apps and scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

***virtualenv*** say's it's faster than ***venv*** in the link below.
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/
And a lot of people say's the same.

What do they mean by faster?
Faster when **creating the virtual environment**
or
when **running apps and scripts?**

I'm new to python, from rails and ruby.
looking for python's virtual environment which fits for the new Django project.

Comment: FWIW, I love [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org) for this…

Comment: @deceze Thank you for the comment. I haven't googled a lot about Poetry, but used Pipenv before. virtualenv and venv seem like a common choice in python 3.3 and above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment says `venv` is slower due to not having the `app-data` seed method. AFAICT, [`app-data` is just a cache used for installing packages from local cache](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html?highlight=app%20data%20seed), and the other references I've found imply its primary benefit is in installing the bootstrap packages in the virtual environment (`pip`, `setuptools`, `wheel`) when it's created from the cache, rather than pulling them from PyPI.

In short, they're referring to a minor speed-up (larger if you have a slow network) in creating the virtual environment; there's nothing special about it in terms of run time performance for scripts running within the environment.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it helped me understand about it a lot. gonna stick with venv then. Thanks!

Comment: the `venv` module also installs from bundled wheels -- but it's 5-10x slower than virtualenv.  if you're making a lot of virtualenvs that 3 second pause can be pretty disruptive.  additionally `venv` doesn't come with `wheel` so you either have to post-install it or deal with the `bdist_wheel` red-scary-warning that comes from pip

Comment: @AnthonySottile: `venv` uses `ensurepip` (which uses a bundled copy of `pip` and `setuptools` that ships with Python itself to perform the original installation), but since that bundled copy is often out of date, `venv` tells `ensurepip` (via the `--upgrade` argument) to follow up that installation by immediately updating both packages from PyPI, so unless the bundled packages are up-to-date, you end up using remote resources, not just bundled stuff (oddly, `venv` has a `--upgrade-deps` argument that seems to tell `venv` to recheck `pip` and `setuptools` for updates *again*).

Comment: Basically, `virtualenv` uses a cache that's updated dynamically (and so is more likely to contain the most recent package versions), `venv` uses a static cache followed by a dynamic update; makes sense `venv` would be slower. On not coming with `wheel`, my response is "Meh". You're setting up a new virtual environment, you'll be installing many packages into it anyway, the incremental cost to manually install `wheel` is trivial.